# How can I produce a print that shows only one or two colors, rather than all three, in color film?

Tags: film, developing, effect

Say I wanted the final result to be a print that displayed only (or all but) the green elements in a color photo. What are some ways I could go about producing it?

This could involve any step of the process - exposing or developing film or prints.

Bonus: is/was special effect film with only one or two color emulsion layers, rather than the full three, ever sold?

Comment: What do you want done with the green elements? Remove green and be any resulting color or go to black and white (selective color style)...are you talking about green elements or one of the emulsion layers in total?

Answer (score 4):

> Say I wanted the final result to be a print that displayed only (or all but) the green elements in a color photo. What are some ways I could go about producing it?

If you are working with digital images (after scanning your film), you can use the channel mixer. It may take some thought and calculation to figure out what percentages to use for each channel. Here is an example:

- Original image:

  [image: original]
- Green "removed" by mixing (R: 50%, G: 0%, B: 50%) into the Green channel.

  [image: RB]

> This could involve any step of the process - exposing or developing film or prints.

If you are using traditional film and darkroom processes with an enlarger, you can "remove" the Green from the final print by approximating the effects of channel mixing.

1. Shoot slide film or make a standard color print.
2. Make a B&W copy negative through a red filter.
3. Make a B&W copy negative through a blue filter.
4. Expose the paper to the Red negative using Red and Green light.  Expose to Green at 50% intensity or duration.
5. Expose the print to the Blue negative using Blue and Green light.  Expose to Green at 50% intensity or duration.

You could also use a magenta filter (RGB -G = Magenta), but then everything will be pink, which may not be what you want.

> Bonus: is/was special effect film with only one or two color emulsion layers, rather than the full three, ever sold?

- Original [Technicolor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technicolor) was a two-color Red-Green process. Simulate digitally by mixing (R: 0%, G: 100%, B: 0%) into the Blue channel.

  [image: RG]
- To reproduce with film, you can use B&W copy negatives exposed through Red and Cyan filters.

For other color processes, see [list of color film systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_color_film_systems) on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about showing what each emulsion layer of the film captured: You can't, really, with conventional color film. To do what you want you would need to be able to seperate each of the layers and print them individually.

Even if you use filtered light to prevent green light from shining through the negative while printing, the green layer of the negative has density and will affect the transmission of the red and blue light through the film in the same way that colored filters affect the tonal density of various colored objects in B&W photos.

Also consider that each layer does not record *only* colors of light that the other two do not. There's a lot of overlap, just like our retinas and Bayer masked digital sensors have, in the sensitivities of the various layers in the film to different wavelengths of light.

To see the isolated response of each emulsion layer in a film, you would need three separate films with only one of the emulsion layers on each film.